# Background image doesn't show up in Gmail

Tags: html, email, gmail

I coded an html email, and just tested in Gmail. Everything shows up fine besides for a background image. I put the background image on my wrapper table, like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="4px solid grey" align="left"  background="http://www.totalrecallsolutions.com/corporate/email templates/images/appt_reminder_one_bg.jpg">
```

And still, there is no image showing up in Gmail. I understood from my google searches that this is the correct way to make a background image show up in Gmail. So why is it not showing up?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just to eliminate the possibility, have you tried with a URL that does not contain a space?

Comment: what do you mean, does not contain a space?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the url with spaces, there's another thing, Gmail doesn't allow `url()` attribute in inline css

> Don't use background images. Gmail, among others, will ignore any
>   url() attribute in an inline style, and the simple background= tag
>   attribute. You can use background colors if you wish (bgcolor tag
>   attribute or background-color: css statement).

Here is the link where I read that: http://groundwire.org/support/articles/css-and-email-newsletters

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has added support for background and background-image properties last February (according to [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)).

But in order for it to show, your code must contain at least one < img > tag. You can use  spacer.gif to trick it (or any transparent image for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had CSS styles defined for background-repeat and background-size in a style tag that was being transformed to a single inline background: no-repeat/cover that was overriding the background attribute for my table. Using just [table background="image-url"] worked for me

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30119877)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is NOT to select / search for an individual image when setting the theme. The image MUST be in an album, even if it's just 1 picture. You can then set it as your background